# viewpager2 to load only first fragment without offscreenPageLimit

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have viewpager2(tablayout) with several fragments which all have network request. I want to load the api(in fragment) when the fragment gets selected and i don't want to destroy fragment when other tab gets selected so i set `offscreenPageLimit` to 7 as I have 7 tabs. Now when i load the app it will call all the 7 apis and the app becomes slow. I want to load the first fragment api and if the user goto the other fragment then it will call the other api & so on.

Any solution will help.

Comment: I had the same problem as you, I went back to using the old version and it ran fast.